# NHibernate map one-to-many relationship with intermediate table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

How to define mapping without intermediate `class PostTag` creation? I have three tables

```
t_post(id...)
t_tag(id, name)
t_post_tag(id,post_id, tag_id)
```

I want to have a collection with Tags in Post type
classes:

```
class Post
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
}
```

mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Sample.Core" namespace="Sample.Core.Domain.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Post" table="t_post" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="System.Int64" unsaved-value="-1"  generator="identity">
    </id>
...
    <bag name="Tags" lazy="true" cascade="none" inverse="true">
      <key column="post_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="Tag" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Sample.Core" namespace="Sample.Core.Domain.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Tag" table="t_tag" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="System.Int64" unsaved-value="-1"  generator="identity">
    </id>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To map pairing table, without explicit Entity representing it, we have to use `<many-to-many>`. Also attribute `table="..."` must be present - to instruct NHibernate about that pairing table. *(In case, that we assign Tags into Posts, we should **not** mark such mapping as inverse)*

```
<bag name="Tags" table="t_post_tag"
    lazy="true" cascade="none" inverse="true">
  <key column="post_id"/>
  <!--<one-to-many class="Tag" />-->
  <many-to-many class="Tag" column="tag_id"/>
</bag>
```

[6.3. Collections of Values and Many-To-Many Associations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues)

> A collection of entities with its own table corresponds to the relational notion of many-to-many association. A many to many association is the most natural mapping of a .NET collection but is not usually the best relational model.

```
<many-to-many
    column="column_name"                               (1)
    class="ClassName"                                  (2)
    fetch="join|select"                                (3)
    not-found="ignore|exception"                       (4)
/>
```

> (1)   column (required): The name of the element foreign key column.
>   (2)   class (required): The name of the associated class.
>   (3)   fetch (optional, defaults to join): enables outer-join or sequential select fetching for this association. This is a special case; for full eager fetching (in a single SELECT) of an entity and its many-to-many relationships to other entities, you would enable join fetching not only of the collection itself, but also with this attribute on the `<many-to-many>` nested element.
>   (4)   not-found (optional - defaults to exception): Specifies how foreign keys that reference missing rows will be handled: ignore will treat a missing row as a null association.

[6.8. Bidirectional Associations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional)

> A bidirectional association allows navigation from both "ends" of the association. Two kinds of bidirectional association are supported:
>
> - `one-to-many`    set or bag valued at one end, single-valued at the other
> - `many-to-many`    set or bag valued at both ends

[23.2. Author/Work](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-mappings-authorwork) *(contains full example)*

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, Radim. You saved me a lot of time.